# Why is RxJS pipe in ngOnInit not executed when the Observable is initialised at class level?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngoninit

When the Observable is initialised at the class property declaration level, why does the pipe in `ngOnInit` is not being fired when the async pipe unwraps the Observable?

I know I can do the initialisation in `ngOnInit` itself but I am just trying to get a better understanding of how RxJS streams work. I am also aware I can call `subscribe()` in `ngOnInit` but that is not my intention.

I have tried doing things like adding a fake loading to "delay" the template rendering in hopes to delay the async pipe but it is still not working.

Component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  items$: Observable<Item[]> = this.dataService.getItems();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items$.pipe(
      tap(data => {
        console.log('items', data);     // <--- this doesn't get called
      })
    )
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you move the pipe to the property instead? `items$: Observable<Item[]> = this.dataService.getItems().pipe(tap(...));`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes it does, as expected. (I am aware of this btw)

Comment: If you want to do it in the init, you need to re-assign I believe. `this.items$ = this.items$.pipe(...)`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn is right, pipe returns a new observable it doesn't modify the original.

Answer (score 5):

While there are good comments on how to fix it, I'll explain why it is so.

> tap (or do in the old version of RxJS) -> Transparently perform
> actions or side-effects, such as logging (as definition already says).

In your case, you don't `.subscribe()` to your Observable, and
that's why you don't see your "Item" logged in the console. You got some options.

1. Option to subscribe in the template using `| async` pipe.
2. Or using `.subsribe()` in your component.

---

### Using async pipe

You could also tap directly on the observable and do not need to subscribe/unsubscribe, because that's handled by `| async` pipe.

```html
<div *ngIf="items$ | async"></div>
```

```js
  items$: Observable<Item[]> = this.dataService.getItems().pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      console.log('items', data);
    })
  );

  ngOnInit(): void {}
```

---

### Using .subscribe()

If you add `.subscribe()` your going to start getting console logs. Though then you also need to unsubscribe after your done.

```js
    this.items$.pipe(
      tap(data => {
        console.log('items', data);
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fcp9fz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts